# Google Play Store Apache Cordova Vulnerabilities (Cordova version should be higher than 4.1)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, google-play, hybrid-mobile-app

I have already built my APK with the **cordova 6.4.0 cli** but the APK is not accepted by the Google PlayStore. I have included cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js file but I don't know the version of these files.

Can any one tell me how I can check the version of these two files? If not, then where can I get the latest versions so I can upload the **apk** to Google Play Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a problem of your `cordova.js` or `cordova_plugins.js`, it's error is caused because your cordova platform version is outdated. You can check your current cordova platform version typing in terminal `cordova platform ls`, it should print an input similar to:

```
Installed platforms:
   android 5.2.2
   ios 4.2.1
Available platforms: 
   amazon-fireos ~3.6.3 (deprecated)
   blackberry10 ~3.8.0
   browser ~4.1.0
   firefoxos ~3.6.3
   osx ~4.0.1
   webos ~3.7.0
```

Therefore, this version number is also placed at `projectPath/platforms/android/cordova/version`.

For updating, you can use `cordova platform update android`, but you should be careful with this command, cause can cause problems in your project (specifically if your project is a little bit old), make sure to have a working backup before doint that.

Comment: Also I would like to know how to get these two files i.e cordova.js and cordova_plugins.js .